# A function inside an if structure

Tags: php, function, if-statement

can I put a function in PHP inside a if structure? like this:

```
<?php
    if(true){
         function HelloWorld(){
             echo "Hello World!!!";
         }
         HelloWorld();
    }
?>
```

because I have tried and it works, but I don't know if it is correct or not. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

This is perfectly legal - it simply defines the function within the if statement block. That said, quite *why* you'd want to do this is somewhat of a mystery.

It's also worth noting that this function will be available in the global scope (i.e.: outside of the if statement block), as...

> All functions and classes in PHP have
>   the global scope - they can be called
>   outside a function even if they were
>   defined inside and vice versa.

See the PHP [User-defined functions manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) for more information.

Comment: well thats what a lambda basically is

Comment: @Doug: ehm ... What?! No, a lambda is definitly something very different than a function, that gets only defined under specific circumstances :D

Comment: @KingCrunch, yeah you're right. I thought you could use something like that for a lambda, but you can't exactly pass it around, since Php's way of passing around functions is by string. Thats not exactly anonymous.

Comment: -1 It does *NOT* define the function into the scope of the `if` statement (actually, the `if` statement doesn't even have it's own scope). It will define a global function, just like any other PHP function declaration statement.

Comment: @nikic I'd already re-worded (most likely whilst you were leaving your comment). I meant that it's *defined* within the if statment, not that it's only available/callable within that scope, etc. I'll use the word scope more carefully in the future. :-)

Comment: How about a performance increase? PHP doesn't need to parse it, right? Or am I way off?

Comment: Reason why: it could be combined with function_rename which returns true only if it succeeded: if( rename_function( 'old', 'old_dontuse' )) { function old() ... etc.

Answer (score 9):

As [middaparka says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912830/php-a-function-inside-an-if-structure/5912852#5912852), this is perfectly legal, but in terms of using it, you might want to check if a function exists before declaring it:

```
if (!function_exists("foo"))
{
    function foo()
    {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

- [`function_exists` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

Answer (score 6):

It looks a bit strange, but yes it's legal

As of PHP 5.3 if you need a function with a limited scope (say for a callback) you can use [anonymous functions / closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add an answer here, because there's a caveat that isn't addressed in the other answers.

Based on my testing in 5.3, it appears that functions that are defined inside `if` structures are defined at runtime, rather than at compile time like other functions.

For example, outside a conditional block, this:

```
foo();
function foo(){
   echo 'foo!';
}
```

works fine because the function is defined at compile time, and executed at runtime. But calling the function before defining it while inside a condition block:

```
if(1){
   foo(); // Call to undefined function!
   function foo(){
      echo 'foo!';
   }
}
```

Will produce a `call to undefined function` error, at least as of version 5.3.

But defining the function in an if block before calling it is valid:

```
if(1){       
   function foo(){
      echo 'foo!';
   }
   foo(); // No errors, since function is defined!
}
```

So there is a major gotcha to be aware of when defining functions inside a conditional: the function must be defined in the code before calling the function, since conditional functions don't seem to get defined at compile time.

The OP also asked about performance. If the conditional function is defined at runtime instead of compile time like most other functions, then this function will not benefit from performance boosters like OpCode caching, which depending on the circumstances, could slow down your application. For example, if your master php file looked like:

```
if($IsLoggedIn){
   // include files/functions and bootstrap here...
}
```

Then the entire application might not benefit from OpCode caching at all.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, according to [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> Any valid PHP code may appear inside a
>   function, even other functions and
>   class definitions.

Personally I haven't had a situation in which I'd actually do such a thing. Most of the time it would be easier to group your functions on a place where it actually can be found! ;-)