# Call to undefined function on setting referrer script

Tags: php, curl, undefined

I am using this script to either set the referrer to the url or if the referrer is empty or cookie is set, hit the image.
The code below is what I have so far, the curl function part works if i put it in a file on it's own but am having trouble putting it with the cookie part.

The error is Call to undefined function geturl()

```
<?php
$image = 'image_url';


if($_COOKIE["6346"] == 1) {
$show = 0;
} 

else {
$show = 1;
$hours = rand(24,68);
setcookie('6346', 1, time()+(60*60*$hours));

}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
$goodreferer = 0;
}
else {
$goodreferer = 1;
}

if ($show == 1 && $goodreferer == 0) {
echo geturl('url(dot)com', 'referer(dot)com');

function geturl($url, $referer) { 


    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg,text/html,application/xhtml+xml'; 
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive'; 
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'; 
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)'; 

    $process = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 

    $return = curl_exec($process); 
    curl_close($process); 

    return $return; 

} 
}
else {
header('Location: ' . $image);

exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`When a function is defined in a conditional manner its definition must be processed prior to being called.` from the PHP Manual  [Conditional functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php#example-148).

So try define the `geturl()` before its been called.
Try this SO post too [Php - a function inside an if structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912830/php-a-function-inside-an-if-structure)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function before it's defined. Move the function to the top of the file. Also, you should not define the function in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define your function inside an if() control structure.  That is a sure recipe for confusion.  It's like multiple inheritance -- just because you CAN does not mean you SHOULD!

I think if you use good indenting of the control structures, you will find that your logic is easier to follow and the code is easier to debug.  This version of the script works correctly.
http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_user1923808.php

```
<?php // RAY_temp_user1923808.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$image = 'image_url';

if( isset($_COOKIE["6346"]) && ( $_COOKIE["6346"] == 1) )
{
    $show = 0;
}
else
{
    $show = 1;
    $hours = rand(24,68);
    setcookie('6346', 1, time()+(60*60*$hours));
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
    $goodreferer = 0;
}
else
{
    $goodreferer = 1;
}

if ($show == 1 && $goodreferer == 0)
{
    echo geturl('url(dot)com', 'referer(dot)com');
}
else
{
    header('Location: ' . $image);
    exit;
}

function geturl($url, $referer) {


    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg,text/html,application/xhtml+xml';
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)';

    $process = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $return = curl_exec($process);
    curl_close($process);

    return $return;
}
```