# Form using function calculate BMI and display different comment. Fatal error and not displaying correctly

Tags: php, forms, function, if-statement

I am creating a form that uses function to calc BMI. Two questions.

1. the comment (underweight/normal weight/...) should output differently depending on the BMI calculated, however no matter what value BMI is, it always outputs UNDERWEIGHT. What do I need to do so that it works?
2. "Fatal error: Call to undefined function bmi() in..." a fatal error is displayed although the function works. Could anyone teach me how to get rid of this error? Thank you so much.

   ```
   <form name="bmi" method="GET" action="test.php">
     Mass in kilogram (kg):
     <input type="text" name="mass" id="mass" size="15">
     <br> 

     Height in meter (m):
     <input type="text" name="height" id="height" size="15">
     <br>

     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
   </form>

   <?php
   if ($_GET['submit']) { 
     $mass = $_GET['mass'];
     $height = $_GET['height'];

     function bmi($mass,$height) {
       $bmi = $mass/($height*$height);
       return $bmi;
     } 

     if ($bmi <= 18.5) {
       $output = "UNDERWEIGHT";

     } else if ($bmi > 18.5 AND $bmi<=24.9 ) {
       $output = "NORMAL WEIGHT";

     } else if ($bmi > 24.9 AND $num<=29.9) {
       $output = "OVERWEIGHT";

     } else if ($bmi > 30.0) {
       $output = "OBESE";
     }
   }
   echo "Your BMI value is  " . bmi($mass,$height). "  and you are : "; 
   echo "$output";
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A function inside an if structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912830/a-function-inside-an-if-structure)

Comment: Properly indenting your code might give you a better idea why this isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the function before your if clause:

```
if ($_GET['submit']) { 
    $mass = $_GET['mass'];
    $height = $_GET['height'];

    function bmi($mass,$height) {
        $bmi = $mass/($height*$height);
        return $bmi;
    }   

    $bmi = bmi($mass,$height); //<--- this is critical

    if ($bmi <= 18.5) {
        $output = "UNDERWEIGHT";

        } else if ($bmi > 18.5 AND $bmi<=24.9 ) {
        $output = "NORMAL WEIGHT";

        } else if ($bmi > 24.9 AND $bmi<=29.9) {
        $output = "OVERWEIGHT";

        } else if ($bmi > 30.0) {
        $output = "OBESE";
    }
    echo "Your BMI value is  " . $bmi . "  and you are : "; 
    echo "$output";
}
```

Comment: Your `echo` statements should also be moved inside the `if`.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, that too.

Comment: In the second [else if] statement [$num] must change to [$bmi]

Answer (score 0):

1. Your $output is always the same because your IF statement is will NEVER run.
   U must set $bmi variable with some value before IF statement, so u can add
   `$bmi = bmi($mass, $height)` before IF statement, and then instead call bmi function in echo command you can use `$bmi` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($_GET['submit']) { 
    $mass = $_GET['mass'];
    $height = $_GET['height'];

    $height2 = ($height*$height);
    $bmi = $mass/$height2; //<--- this is critical

    if ($bmi <= 18.5) {
        $output = "UNDERWEIGHT";

        } else if ($bmi > 18.5 AND $bmi<=24.9 ) {
        $output = "NORMAL WEIGHT";

        } else if ($bmi > 24.9 AND $bmi<=29.9) {
        $output = "OVERWEIGHT";

        } else if ($bmi > 30.0) {
        $output = "OBESE";
    }
    echo "Your BMI value is  " . $bmi . "  and you are : "; 
    echo "$output";
}
?>
```